# Гугл таблицы. Как с помощью регулярного выражения вырезать несколько однотипных выражений из одной строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-spreadsheet

Есть закодированные строки вида:

**2201.1204# Dell; @ Маша; @ Петя; Разгрузка вагонов.**

**2201.1203# Dell; @ Иван; Доставка заказчику.**

Мне нужно вытащить имена.
Одно, первое просто **=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"@\s(.+);")** - **Маша**

А как получит все?

Два значения **Маша** и **Петя** в первом случае,
и **Иван** во втором.

Comment: Перечитал всю документацию. Не нашел решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И Вуаля:
**=IFNA(TEXTJOIN("
";TRUE;ArrayFormula(trim(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(D85;"(?:@\s)(?:.+);");";"); "@ "; "")))); "?!")**

Конструкция громоздкая, зато работает.
Вытаскиваю все имена ***независимо от их количества*** и собираю через перевод каретки в одну ячейку. Получаю:

---

**Маша**

**Петя**

---

Если искомых значений нет сигнализирую:

---

**?!**

---

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае гораздо удобнее работать с функцией:

```js
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern, groupId, separator="", keepEmpty=false) {
  let matches = Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern, 'g')), x => x[groupId]);
  if (!keepEmpty) {
    matches = matches.filter(Boolean);
  }
  if (separator) {
    return [matches.join(separator)];
  }
  return [matches];
}
```

Затем в ячейке достаточно указать `=ExtractAllRegex(D85; "@\s*(\S+);"; 1)` . или `=ExtractAllRegex(D85; "@\s*(\S+);"; 1, "", 0)`.

**Подробности**:

- `input` - адрес текущей ячейки
- `pattern` - регулярное выражение
- `groupId` - номер захватывающей подмаски (0 - целое совпадение, 1 - значение первой подмаски и т.д.)
- `separator` - текст-разделитель для найденных значений
- `keepEmpty` - оставлять пустые значения.

Пример работы скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]